# Error in wevtutil while installing ETW manifest

Tags: etw

I am getting the following error while trying to install an ETW manifest on a machine running windows server 2008 R2:

> The publishers and channels are installed succesfully. However, we
>   can't enable one or more publishers and channels. The specified
>   channel could not be found. Check channel configuration.

As the error message says, the publishers and channels were installed, but were not enabled. The main problem for me that the channels were not showing up in EventViewer.

Answer (score 1):

While tracking down the issue i started by uninstalling all the manifests that are involved in the installation process.

After uninstalling i did an enum providers

```
wevtutil ep
```

and one of the manifests that i should have uninstalled was still in the list

I have seen several cases where the ETW database has been corrupted in the past and the only answer i know of is to un corrupt it yourself. All the pertinent stuff (that i know of) is stored in the registry under the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT
```

So jump there, and then into the Publishers subkey. I was looking for the provider guid that was supposed to be uninstalled. When i got there there was a special value

```
"Enabled"=dword:00000
```

I imagine if you don't know which publisher was causing the issue you might be able to look for this value to identify the one that is causing problems.

I deleted the registry entry for this provider (which effectively uninstalls it from the system) and everything was back to normal.